# Как выровнять блок параллельно с другим

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не БЛОК2 не поднимается параллельно левому большому блоку. Не могу понять, у всех div прописано  display: inline-block;

Comment: если `inline-block`, то задавайте таким блокам `vertical-align: top`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло!